# How is mustard made?

Tags: condiments, mustard

I'd like to make mustard soon. What's the basic process to start with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mustard is one of those simple condiments to make, and is fun to experiment with. At it's most basic mustard is two ingredients:

- Mustard Seed
- Liquid

There are endless variations from there.

Mustard seed comes in white, yellow, brown and black variations. I suggest buying whole and grinding them yourself using either a mortar & pestle or coffee/spice grinder. (Don't use a coffee grinder that you use for grinding coffee! You'll end up with mustard flavored coffee).

Liquids can be water, vinegar, wine, or even beer. Using vinegar/wine will help it last longer than water or beer would.

Once you've fine ground (of course there are coarse ground varieties too) your mustard simply mix it with the liquid until it is the desired consistency.

Additional ingredients can be added to taste. Honey, turmeric (gives yellow mustard its color), sugar, etc. are all possibilities.

**Update:** I forgot to mention that mustard needs time for the flavors to mix. This can take anywhere from a few hours to weeks. A fresher mustard tends to be hotter, but an aged mustard can often taste "better" with a slight loss of that initial heat. Refrigerated mustard will keep it's heat longer. Also note, mustard made with water should definitely be refrigerated and consumed quicker than others.

Comment: What does "heat" mean, spicyness? Also, why wine conserves the mustard?

Comment: I feel the need to comment that grinding is *an option* (but you need to leave plenty of space and liquid for dry mustard seed to swell in the liquid) as I often make unground (seedy) mustard rather than even cracking it. The mucilage is impressive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of recipes for the mustard, but there are few important tricks to know:

1. water temperature:the colder the water the hotter the mustard
2. vinegar amount: as water increases the hotness, the vinegar does the opposite. You can balance the hotness level by using more or less vinegar.
3. wait for 3-4 days to judge your mustards taste, because it's really not good in the beginning.
4. I always have good results by using honey, apple vinegar, eggs and himalayan salt
   Enjoy!

Answer (score -3):

I haven't made mustard yet there are tons of recipes to do this. For example at food.com [here](http://www.food.com/recipe-finder/all/mustard) they have lots of recipes listed.

The [first recipe](http://www.food.com/recipe/mustard-366124) returned on the site combines all the required ingredients, lets it sit in the fridge overnight then mixes it in the blender.

Good luck!

Comment: -1: This answer doesn't really bring much to the table.

Comment: He wanted to know how to make it... there are recipes at the link that tell him how.

Comment: It's still pretty weak as far as content goes. Answers should have more to them than "there's lots of stuff here, go read". You also hadn't added the second paragraph of your answer at that time. If you fleshed out your answer more I'd consider removing my downvote.

Comment: I (half) agree with @hobodave.  There's nothing wrong with copying the recipe from your link and then sighting the source where you found it.  @hobodave I think the response is in the same context as the question.  The question is very general and doesn't describe what it is to be use for.

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting "flamed" for this, but it's actually not a bad thing (that you're getting flamed)