# what is the ideal ratio to mix mustard powder with flour?

Tags: mustard

Hi I am making mustards and soon planning to do it commercially too.
My question is the rate of mustard powder&wheat flour mixture ratio. Otherwise it's too hot and too expensive to sell. I welcome also other solutions to use less mustard powder.
Any recommendations would highly be appreciated.

Comment: The question about the right ratio seems entirely opinion-based: mix it until it's the strength you want. The question about other solutions is maybe okay, though I think you might need to clarify: when you say "making mustards" do you mean you're making a dry mustard powder, so you have to use something dry to bulk it up and reduce the heat? Or are you making mustard, the condiment (a paste), where usually the addition of water and vinegar dilutes the heat plenty?

Comment: 1) Flour? Never seen a recipe containing flour for mustard ever.
2) Assuming it's not uncommon to add flour, wouldn't the ratio be one of those well guarded company secrets?

Comment: I see you have another question [about stabilizing hot sauces](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/65148/how-can-i-stabilize-my-hot-sauces-without-using-chemicals) you're going to take in to production. No offense, but are you sure you're in the right business? Perhaps you are, but, and this is coming from a complete idiot, I would hire professionals to tell me about this kind of stuff, and not rely on public forums for this kind of information.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/how-is-mustard-made

Comment: Thanks for all replies, after all these comments I am not going to add anything else than real mustard powder. I already have an amazing recipe and I am not going to touch it. Let it be a little expensive I don't care and I think real mustard lovers will don't care etiher :)

Comment: Hi me neither I don't see any recipe with flour, but I saw some mustards in the market with wheat flour added. But I don't think it's a good idea and I'm not gonna do it.

Answer (score 5):

If want to sell [mustard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustard_(condiment)), make mustard, not a stretched fake mustard. You would be cheating your customers and depending on your location the authorities might be after you, too.

The "sharpness" of a mustard is balanced by the ratios of different mustard seeds, [white/yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_mustard), [brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica_juncea) or [black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica_nigra) and the temperatures used during preperation. Typically, vinager is added and sometimes other flavouring compounds like other herbs, spices or honey.

Answer (score 4):

There is not flour in mustard. Typical ingredients include sugars (usually brown), turmeric, paprika, garlic, and other flavoring spices. The mustard seed powder and the sugar compose most of the "structure" of the sauce. You would moderate the hotness by adding more sugar or mustard seed.